# Error al actualizar tabla en Yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

Buenas tardes amigos, acudo a ustedes para que me ayuden a realizar un update a una tabla en yii 2, les muestro el codigo de mi controlador para que puedan darme sugerencias:

```
    public function actionCancelarconsulta(){    

// asigno a  variables los datos que utilizare para la actualizacion       
        $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');        
        $idActualiza = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $nombreActualiza = Yii::$app->user->identity->nombre;
        $apellidosActualiza = Yii::$app->user->identity->apellidos;

// aqui solo concateno el id y el nombre y apellidos de quien esta realizando la actualizacion
        $actualizadoPor = $idActualiza." - ".$nombreActualiza." ".$apellidosActualiza;

// Estos son los campos que recojo de mi vista
        $request = Yii::$app->request;
        $idConsulta = $request->post('idConsulta');
        $motivoCancelacion = $request->post('motivoCancelacion');

// Consulto mi tabla de nombre tratamiento
        $eliminaConsulta = Tratamiento::find()->where(['id' => $idConsulta])->one();  

// verifico que el campo de descripcion no este vacio, si trae datos entra a la operacion
        if (!empty($motivoCancelacion)) {

//Aqui es donde asigno los valores a los campos que deseo actualizar
            $eliminaConsulta->estatus = 2;
            $eliminaConsulta->actualizadoPor = $actualizadoPor;
            $eliminaConsulta->motivoCancelacion = $motivoCancelacion;
            $eliminaConsulta->fechaCancelacion = $fecha;

// si se inserta procedo a la vista principal (Tabla general)
            if ($eliminaConsulta->update()) {

                $searchModel = new TratamientoSearch();
                $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

                return $this->render('index', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                ]);

// sino muestro el error (Siempre cae en esta condicion y no se actualiza el registro)                
            }else{
                echo "No se inserto";

            }

// si el campo motivoCancelacion no trae datos lo redirecciono a la misma vista con un mensaje de advertencia
        }else{
            $table = Tratamiento::find()->where(['id' => $idConsulta])->one();
            $msg = "campoincompleto";
            return $this->render('cancelarconsulta', array(
                'idConsulta' => $idConsulta,
                'table' => $table,
                'msg' => $msg,
                ));
        }

    }

    public function actionAsignarnumconsultas($id){

        #$totalConsultas = Tratamiento::find()->where(['idPaciente' => $id])->count();
        $totalConsultas = 1;
        if ($totalConsultas == 1) {
            echo "<option value='primera vez' >Primera Vez</option>";
        }elseif($totalConsultas > 1){
            echo "<option value='subsecuente' >Subsecuente</option>";
        }else{
            echo "<option> --- </option>";
        }

    }
```

El detalle esta que no actualiza y siempre me pasa al error de no actualizado.

Cabe menciona que en diferentes ocaciones he actualizado de esta manera, pero en esta ocacion no logro ver donde pueda estar el error...
Les agradeceria mucho que me echaran una mano

De antemano gracias

Comment: ingnoren la funcion de abajo " actionAsignarnumconsultas " :)

Comment: creo que deberias cambiar **$eliminaConsulta->update()** por **$eliminaConsulta->save()** o bien save(false) para forzar la actualización

Comment: @PatrickArguello save al fin de cuentas llama a update() cuando isNewRecord es false, pero bien como te menciona, y ese puede ser el posible problema, ya te aseguraste que $eliminaConsulta exista, es decir que te traiga algun registro? Ahora bien, si si existe puedes probar con $elimnaConsulta->save(false) como te mencionaban, si guarda quiere decir que es un error en tu rules del modelo al momento de validar

Answer (score -1):

Lo mas probable es que tengas errores de validación las cuales están definidas en tu modelo, para saberlo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if ($eliminaConsulta->validate() && $eliminaConsulta->update()) {

        }else{
            echo "No se inserto";
            // Esto te mostrará un arreglo de errores de validación.
            var_dump($eliminaConsulta->getErrors());
            die;

        }
```

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, sería ideal que añadieras una descripción de por qué funcionaría y/o la diferencia entre hacer save o update en este caso particular.